# Change textsize in afterTextChanged

Tags: android, textview

There is a EditText whose width is fixed and `maxLines = 1`. I want to change the text size when length of text is increasing.

```
override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    val paint = edit_text.paint
    var textSize = edit_text.textSize
    var newWidth = paint.measureText(s.toString())
    while (newWidth >= edit_text.width) {
        textSize -= 1
        paint.textSize = textSize
        newWidth = paint.measureText(s.toString())
    }
    edit_text.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize)
}
```

As you see, when the `newWidth` is larger than `width`, I will search a new textSize (in the while loop).

However when I input word one by one, there is a strange bug.

As you see, now the text has become upper limit.

[image]

Now I input another char
`K`.

[image]

I can nor figure out why the new char appears singly.

Comment: i am just curious `val paint =` are you using some js ?

Comment: Move this `edit_text.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize)` inside the while loop

Comment: and i dont think you need while loop in there, since afterTextChange should be an event triggered after the text change

Comment: i am only not sure cuz you are using JS >.<

Comment: Lol, I am using Kotlin insetead of js.

Comment: yeah, whatever; just move the settext inside the while it should fix it\

Comment: As you see I want to change text size, but I do not know which textsize is suitable so I have to use while loop.

Comment: It's not a good idea. Because I only need to set textsize when I find suitable one.

Comment: i guess this while loop is the reason why its not working as expected, give it a try and use it without the while loop increase the 1 to lets say 10 to check if the bug reproduced or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:inputType="text"` works for me. But I do not know why.